# prove by induction that $(a^n - b^n)$ is a multiple of $(a - b)$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Okay so I just finished a final in discrete mathematics and I could not figure out how to finish this proof:

"Prove by mathematical induction, that $(a^n - b^n)$ is a multiple of $(a - b)$ when $a$ and $b$ are integers and $n \geq 1$.

$\underline{Base case: n = 1}$

$(a^1 - b^1) = (a - b)x$

$x = 1$

$a - b = a - b$

$\underline{Inductive Hypothesis:}$

$n = k$ for some $k$

$(a^k - b^k) = (a - b)x$

$\underline{Inductive Step:}$

$n = k + 1$

$(a^{k + 1} - b^{k + 1}) = (a - b)x_1$

$(a \cdot a^{k}) - (b \cdot b^{k}) = (a - b) x_1$

$a \cdot [(a - b)x + b^k] + b \cdot [(a - b)x - a^k]= (a-b)x_1$

$(a -b)xa + ab^k + (a - b)xb - ba^k = (a - b)x_1$

$(a -b)xa + (a - b)xb - ab^k + ba^k = (a - b)x_1$

$(a -b)xa + (a - b)xb + ba^k - ab^k = (a - b)x_1$

.....

I don't know if I did it right but I couldn't get any further than this.

Comment: Are you forced to use induction?

Comment: Yes, not strong induction as well.

Comment: Why are my posts getting downvoted / removed? I am very new here, but I want to fix whatever it is I am doing wrong. I am posting this here because this post got -2 votes and I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: @N.Luscomb: It may be because the tags may be incorrect or maybe some feel its too basic.

Comment: @N.Luscomb The question seems fine to me. You've given context, made the question clear, shown what you tried, said how far you got. (Maybe someone didn't like the title being worded as an instruction or something—the site gets bombarded with homework questions. I'm just guessing though.)

Comment: Your question is much better than a lot of other questions flooding this site. I don't think it deserves to be downvoted, but just be aware that such basic questions have almost surely been posted and answered before, so a quick search for it would be preferable. But I commend you on wanting to finish your exam even after it is over. =)

Comment: @user21820 Agreed. And yet, it is a real pity that none of the six answers below is addressing the main problem the OP seems to have, which is **how induction proofs actually work**. As we know, the induction step of a proof by induction that P(n) holds for every n, simply cannot start with "Assume P(n+1) then..." and yet this is what the OP does above, which leads them to a deadend, honestly signalled by "I don't know if I did it right but I couldn't get any further than this". As long as the OP does not identify this misconception, they will fail to "build" any coherent proof by induction.

Comment: @Did: Right. And none of the answers even did the induction in a logically cogent manner... N.Luscomb: To make it clear, induction for any property $P$ asserts that from $P(0)$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ ( P(n) ⇒ P(n+1) )$ you can deduce $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ ( P(n) )$. So before you can even use induction on $P$, you must **prove** the two statements that it requires. If you do not know how that works, you would need to learn basic logic (which clearly your course failed to teach)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed $a^k-b^k=(a-b)m,m\in\Bbb Z\implies a^k=b^k+(a-b)m$

We have $a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a\times a^k-b^{k+1}=a[b^k+(a-b)m]-b^{k+1}\\=am(a-b)+ab^k-b^{k+1}\\=am(a-b)+b^k(a-b)\\=(am+b^k)(a-b)$

Comment: I believe this is the answer I was supposed to arrive at, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1)$n=1 : a-b ✓$

Hypothesis: $a^n-b^n$ is a multiple of $(a-b)$.

Step $n+1$:

$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1} =a a^n -b b^n= $

$aa^n-ba^n+ba^n -bb^n=$

$(a-b)a^n +b(a^n -b^n)=$

$(a-b)a^n +bk(a-b)=$

$ (a-b)(a^n +bk).$

(Since by hypothesis: $a^n-b^n =k(a-b)$).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we prove the statement for $n=0,1$ (or $n=1,2$ if you prefer, but the statement is true for $n\geq0$).

Case $n=0$ : $a^0-b^0 = 0 = 0*(a-b)$

Case $n=1$ : $a^1-b^1 = 1*(a-b)$

Now we prove the induction case. Suppose the statement is true for $k\leq n$, and let's prove it for $n+1$:
$$
(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})=(a^n-b^n)(a+b) - a^nb + b^na = (a^n-b^n)(a+b)- ab(a^{n-1} - b^{n-1})
$$

Since both $(a^n-b^n)$ and $(a^{n-1} - b^{n-1})$ are divisible by $(a-b)$ by induction, so is $(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})$ since it is a sum of their multiples.

Comment: Note that we needed to put two cases in the basis case ($n=0$ AND $n=1$), since we use strong induction. In other words to prove the statement for $n+1$ we use both $n$ and $n-1$, so we need two $n$'s for the basis case.

Comment: This is how I wanted to solve it, but it says specifically mathematical induction.(The next question asked for strong mathematical induction)

Comment: Strong induction is not needed here, simply write $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a^{n+1}-a^nb+a^nb-b^{n+1}=(a-b)a^n+b(a^n-b^n)$$ hence if $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$, then $a-b$ also divides $(a-b)a^n+b(a^n-b^n)$, qed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do one step of a long division?

$$
\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b} = a^k + b\frac{(a^k-b^k)}{a-b}
$$

with the remainder being a polynomial in $a$ and $b$ by induction hypothesis.

Answer (score -1):

$$
a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}a^m\cdot b^{n-1-m}$$

Comment: It should be $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}a^m\cdot b^{n-1-m}$$